# Paypal Express Checkout: Error 10001 Timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal

So I'm trying to implement the Paypal Express checkout and keep recieving the above error.

My NV is as follows:

```
METHOD=SetExpressCheckout&
VERSION=204.0&
USER=mylogicn&
PWD=mypwd&
SIGNATURE=mysignature&
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=26.65&
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=GBP&
RETURNURL=https://www.example.com/Basket/NotificationProcessor.ashx?type=paypalsuccess&
CANCELURL=https://www.example.com/Basket/NotificationProcessor.ashx?type=paypalfailure&
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Sale
```

Obviously with certain information changed.
I can't find anything particularly wrong with the request but without fail always returns 10001, with Timeout processing request.

I'm hoping someone here has encountered this before and has a solution.

EDIT:
Here's the code that puts together the request and retrieves the response:

```
string[][,] nv = new string[11][,]
{
    new string[,]{{"METHOD", "SetExpressCheckout" }},
    new string[,]{{"VERSION", "204.0" }},

    new string[,]{{"USER", "myuser"}},
    new string[,]{{"PWD", "mypwd"}},
    new string[,]{{"SIGNATURE","mysig"}},

    new string[,]{{"PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT", "26.65"}},
    new string[,]{{"PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE","GBP"}},

    new string[,]{{"RETURNURL",  "https://www.example.com/Basket/NotificationProcessor.ashx?type=paypalsuccess"}},
    new string[,]{{"CANCELURL", "https://www.example.com/Basket/NotificationProcessor.ashx?type=paypalfailure"}},

    new string[,]{{"PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION", "Sale"}},
    new string[,]{{"NOSHIPPING", "1"}},
};
string q = "?";
foreach(string[,] s in nv)
{
    q += s[0,0] + "=" + s[0,1] + "&";
}
q = q.TrimEnd('&');
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp" + q);
req.Method = "POST";

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
var encoding = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII;
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), encoding))
    {
        string response = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

And Paypals response:

```
TIMESTAMP=2016%2d07%2d11T11%3a10%3a55Z&
CORRELATIONID=dcd0f848a9bb9&
ACK=Failure&
L_ERRORCODE0=10001&
L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Internal%20Error&
L_LONGMESSAGE0=Timeout%20processing%20request
```

Comment: Are you making sure you are reading the entire response? It would be helpful if you add your code (less shared secrets and keys of course. To the question.

Comment: My apologies. I've edited my question to include the code that builds the request and the response I receive.

Answer (score 0):

Error 10001 is an unhandled exception that means there's no better error message available.

As per PayPal [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/#id4ef5b8c2-274a-4965-9c73-c84e6a935d1a)

> You must encode all request field values in a request to PayPal and
>   decode all field values in the response. You must encode and decode
>   individual values; **do not encode or decode the entire message**.
>   Browsers often attempt to encode and decode messages that are
>   redirected to or from them; however, you must verify that encoding and
>   decoding is done correctly and only to field values.

it might happen due to encoding. Try to get rid of it and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was using POST. Simply removing the `req.Method = "POST"` solved the issue.